# How can I sort the results of a 'compare stored queries' fixture using DBFIT?

Tags: dbfit

is it possible to sort the results of a 'compare stored queries' fixture in DBFIT so that the failed results return to the top of the results grid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With version 2.2.0 of DBFIT you can use the command `compare stored queries hide matching rows` to return only failed items. You still get a summary showing how many passed so you don't lose all the detail.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of - `compare stored queries` isn't really designed to be used to compare 1000s upon 1000s of rows.

Any chance you can split the test into smaller tests, eg by comparing only subsets of the data?